# edit child div's height with javascript

Tags: javascript, styles, children

I am working on an exercise that give me the following, and I want to change the heights and widths of the child divs with javascript, and without giving classes or divs to the inner divs

```
<div id="puzzlearea">
    <div>1</div>  <div>2</div>  <div>3</div>  <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>  <div>6</div>  <div>7</div>  <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>  <div>10</div> <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div> <div>14</div> <div>15</div>
</div>
```

I was going for something like this, but I get an error saying I have an undefined object.

```
function loading(){
    var boxes = document.getElementById("puzzlearea").childNodes;
    for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++){
        boxes[i].style.height ='100pt';
    };
 };

window.onload = function(){
     loading();
 };
```

Comment: Can you post a demo http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce the issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6mkYL/

Answer (score 2):

**reason:**

Some of the `childNodes` are text nodes (representing spaces between `<div>`s), which don't have `style` property, so `boxes[i].style` resolves to `undefined` and trying to get `height` of that `undefined` causes the error.

**solution:**

```
var boxes = document.getElementById("puzzlearea").children;
```

**see:**

http://jsfiddle.net/YWz5S/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your javascript is placed after `<div id="puzzlearea">` in the document or else `document.getElementById("puzzlearea")` will return `null`.